# Read all files of a directory or only one file

Tags: perl

How can I write a script that reads all files from a specific directory or only one file from a specific directory depending on what the user provides as argument?

I know that I can open all files from a directory using the following:

```
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Could not open '$dir' for reading: $!\n";

my @files = readdir($dh);

{

#Do something

}

closedir($dh);
```

I also know that I can open only one file from a directory using the following:

```
my $src = $ARGV[0];

open(SRC,'<',$src) or die $!;

{

#Do something

}

close(SRC);
```

Is there a way to detect what the user is providing as argument in order to know if the argument is a directory or only a file? If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`-d` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to check if something is a directory, or the [`-f` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to check if it's a file. One or the other will do, but it's safer to check both so you can catch input that is neither.

```
if ( -d $file_or_dir ) {
    # it's a directory ...
} 
elsif ( -f $file_or_directory ) {
    # it's a file ...
else {
    # it's bad input, so neither
}
```

The command line arguments are in [`@ARGV`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV). It's a simple array that you can read from. You could easily wrap your whole program in a loop so it works for multiple arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the [file test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to check things about a file. `-f` to check if it's a regular file, `-d` to check if it's a directory, and a bunch of others to check for other things.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use v5.10;

my $arg = shift;
my @files;

if( -d $arg ) {
    opendir my $dh, $arg;
    @files = readdir $dh;
}
elsif( -f $arg ) {
    push @files, $arg;
}
else {
    die "$arg is neither a file nor directory";
}
```

Don't forget to filter `.` and `..` out from `readdir`. Consider using [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) instead.

Comment: Why are you insisting on perl v5.10?

Comment: @Borodin To demonstrate good habits. `say` and `state` are available without having to think about it. I consider `strict`, `warnings`, `v5.10`, and `autodie` standard headers to plug some of the worst gotchas.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Schwern, this worked perfectly.